# How to swap two HTML canvas locations on screen with each other?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, canvas

I have two html canvas rendered on screen in a Vue.js app using Vuetify.

When I click a button, I wish the content and functionality of one canvas to swap locations with another canvas, and maintain functionality.

Is there a way to do this using pure CSS or JS?

I have tried a few attempts with css top and left attributes

Comment: Without any code information, it is hard to say anything.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement.